# Coalesce potentially Empty LINQ query results

Tags: c#, linq, coalesce, null-coalescing-operator

Im using Linq to return IDs from 4 cascading dropdown menus.

The user may have selected 1 or more values from either 1 or all of the menus.  From the users selections, Im then quering the text columns of a DataTable for the representative IDs.

If the user selects from the 4th (and lowest level) dropdown, then they would have selected from all those above.

If the user selects "X" from menu 1, "Y" from menu 2, and nothing in the others i would expect to see `results1` with say 10 rows where "X" exists in [Col_1], which would then be queried down to say 5 rows in `results2` where "Y" exists in [Col_2].

**EDIT**
The Code (in a basic form)

```
var results1 = 
    from a in dt.AsEnumerable()
    where stringArray1.Contains([Col1])
    select a;


var results2 = 
    from a in results1
    where stringArray2.Contains([Col2])
    select a;

var results3 = 
    from a in results2
    where stringArray3.Contains([Col3])
    select a;

var results4 = 
    from a in results3
    where stringArray4.Contains([Col4])
    select a;

var results = results4 ?? results3 ?? results2 ?? results1;
```

`results4` depends on the results from `results3`, `results3` on `results2`,  and `results2` on `results1`.

It may be that `results4 - 2` are empty , and therefore I was wondering if I could coalesce these into a final variable, eg:

```
var results = results4 ?? results3 ?? results2 ?? results1;
```

This is throwing the error:

```
Operator '??' cannot be applied to operands of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<AnonymousType#4>'
```

Does anyone have any cunning ideas how to resolve this?  Im trying not to write very long winded code, handling every possible outcome.

Thank you all in advance (hopefully the question makes sense!)

CM

Comment: 'null' and 'empty' are two different things.  Are you really sure you mean 'null' and not 'empty'?

Comment: good point well made. edits coming.

Comment: I think it would be helpful if you posted the LINQ queries used to obtain the data for the 4 results.

Comment: Hey, are you sure the `results` objects are of the same type? if you're mixing anonymous types, they might not be.

Comment: You want an empty coalescing operator

Comment: I cannot escape the feeling of code smell here. Results1-4, stringArray1-4, Col1-4. If you posted information on the actual problem you are trying to solve rather than snippets from your current solution it might be possible to come up with a more elegant approach.

Comment: @Greg Ros, how can the results objects be of differnt types, they are selected from each other

Comment: @Jodrell That comment was posted before the code snippets were added.

Comment: @Morten Mertner - You may well be right.  Ive tried to explain the basics of the problem, which will hopefully get us all a bit closer to an answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So based on the queries you're using, none of the results will ever be `null`.  Some of them may be empty, but they won't be `null`.  This means that the `??` operator won't ever do anything useful.

How do you want this to behave?  Do you want to say, "if this result is empty, use this other one?"  For that use the method I've written below.

```
public static IEnumerable<T> Coalesce<T>(IEnumerable<T> first, IEnumerable<T> second)
{
  if(first == null || !first.Any())
  {
    return second;
  }
  else
  {
    return first;
  }
}
```

This could then be used as:

```
Coalesce(results4, Coalesce(results3, Coalesce(results2, results1)));
```

The result of this is, "return `result4`, unless it's empty.  If it's empty return `results3`.  If `results3` is empty return `results2`, if `results2` is empty return `results1`."

You could make it an extension method if you think you'd use it enough.  It would make it prettier, but would also clutter up intellisense for all of the other `IEnumerable`s so it may not be worth it.

Comment: If you add a `this` keyword before the `first` argument, you can even write: `results4.Coalesce(results3.Coalesce(results2.Coalesce(results1)));`

Comment: @Steven I specifically mention the possibility of making this an extension method, "You could make it an extension method if you think you'd use it enough."  My guess is it won't be used much, if at all, outside of this one context so it shouldn't be an extension method.  If this is something the OP will do a lot, then it may be worth doing.

Comment: Hi there.  I like the look of this answer, but i cant quite implement it.  Im getting the error `System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<T>' does not contain a definition for 'Empty'`.  Any thoughts?

Comment: @CatchingMonkey Edited, it needs to use `Any`.

Comment: @Servy: I didn't really read the answer, just looked at the code, my mistake :-). Your argument against using extension methods is good (so +1 for that and +1 for your answer). I see abuse of extension methods a lot in the project I cooperate.

Comment: Hiya,  sorry to be a pain but I'm now getting `The type arguments for method 'GenericFucntions.Coalesce<T>(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<T>, System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<T>)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.` when i try to use the method `var blah = Coalesce(results2, results1)`.  Damn Generics!

Comment: Is this something to do with the version of .NET being used?  Im still unfortunately using 3.5 here...

Comment: @CatchingMonkey I'm on 3.5 too.  There's nothing from 4.0 or beyond here.

Comment: Not to worry, i got it sorted literally about 2 mins ago.  Thanks for your help!

Comment: @CatchingMonkey From your code it looks like the type of each element is `String`.  Just specify that explicitly if it can't figure it out on its own.

Answer (score 0):

If you didn't want to write long winded code you could do

```
public static IEnumerable<T> SomeOrAll<T>(
    this IEnumerable<T> source, 
    Predicate<T> where)
{
    var results = source.Where(where)
    return results.Any() ? results : source;
}

var results = dt.AsEnumerable()
    .SomeOrAll(a => a.stringArray4.Contains([Col4]))
    .SomeOrAll(a => a.stringArray3.Contains([Col3]))
    .SomeOrAll(a => a.stringArray2.Contains([Col2]))
    .SomeOrAll(a => a.stringArray1.Contains([Col1]));
```

but, I suspect, if you step back a bit, you could do something else. If people needed this extension often it would already exist (perhaps.)

Answer (score 0):

I'd rewrite the query to solve the problem, rather than dealing with it after the fact.

```
public List<string> FilterResults(string first, string second, string third, string fourth)
{
    var query = from a in dt.AsEnumerable()
                let firsts = first != null ? a.Where( x => x.stringArray1.Contains( first ) ) : null,
                let seconds = second != null ? firsts.Where( x => x.stringArray2.Contains( second ) ) : null,
                let thirds = third != null ? seconds.Where( x => x.stringArray3.Contains( third ) ) : null,
                let fourths = fourth != null ? thirds.Where( x => x.stringArray4.Contains( fourth ) ) : null
                select fourths ?? thirds ?? seconds ?? firsts;
    return query.ToList();
}
```

I didn't run this though VS but the general idea should come across.